# akka Actor unit testing using testkit

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, scalatest

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786440/akka-actors-unit-testing-with-scala) examples of using [akka-testkit](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.11/scala/testing.html) when the Actor being tested is responding to an ask:

```
//below code was copied from example link
val actorRef = TestActorRef(new MyActor)
// hypothetical message stimulating a '42' answer
val future = actorRef ? Say42
val Success(result: Int) = future.value.get
result must be(42)
```

But I have an Actor that does not respond to a sender; it instead sends a message to a separate actor.  A simplified example being:

```
class PassThroughActor(sink : ActorRef) {
  def receive : Receive = {
    case _ => sink ! 42
  }
}
```

[TestKit](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/testkit/TestKit.html) has a suite of `expectMsg` methods but I cannot find any examples of creating a test sink Actor that could expect a message within a unit test.

Is it possible to test my `PassThroughActor`?

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: You can create probes and probe actors. Just keep reading in the documentation.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  Obviously a common enough problem.  Was difficult to google though, hence the question.  If you submit an answer I'll vote it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use a [TestProbe](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html#Using_Multiple_Probe_Actors) to solve this:

```
val sink = TestProbe()
val actorRef = TestActorRef(Props(new PassThroughActor(sink.ref)))

actorRef ! "message"

sink.expectMsg(42)
```